# hosting a file on jetty

Tags: jetty

I'm a jetty newbie. I know how to specify servlet names and mappings in the web.xml file by using the `<servlet>` and `<servelet-mapping>` tags, but how do I host general files on my jetty server so I can call on them? Specifically I want to upload some images and an html file. I am using a war file.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use the DefaultServlet to serve images and other static content. The documentation is [here](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/DefaultServlet.html) and an example config would look like this:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>staticAssets</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>staticAssets</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

In your WAR file anything placed inside the static directory will be served under the appropriate URL.

Comment: Where do I put the static directory, under what subfolder of the war file?

Comment: under the root folder it would be `static/`

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a war file, then you don't need to do anything special in Jett (or any other servlet container)

Simply put your HTML and Image files inside the war file. As long as they are someone other than in the `WEB-INF` directory, then they'll be available to clients.

Assuming you're using standard Jetty deployment mechanisms, then if you have a war file called  `myapp.war` and it has the following contents:

```
myapp.war:
    pages/
        index.html
    images/
        logo.png
    WEB-INF/
        classes/
            com/
                example/
                    MyServlet.class
        lib/
            support.jar
```

then your `index.html` page would be available at `http://localhost/myapp/pages/index.html` (typically with a port number in there, for whatever port you're running Jetty on)

Comment: it says it can't find such a url. I would guess I need to tell it to map to that file somehow

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything. How are you running Jetty?